# Not calling watch even after the prop change in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch

I can't use `immediate:true`, except immediate true is another thing I can do? Why watch is not calling even after the data change in prop? Only it is calling for the first time when application loads.

```
export default {
  name: "Tabs",
  data () {
    return {
      init: false,
      currentTab: "tab-0",
      tab: null,
    }
  },
  props: {
    config: {
      type: Object,
      default: undefined
    },
    dynamicSelection: 0
  },
}

watch: {
    config: {
      handler: function (val) { //need to do something }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Can you show the "data change in prop"?

Comment: {"tab":null,"icons":false,"backgroundColor":"","isdark":false,"tabitems":[{"isEnabled":true,"name":"Tab1","content":"menu1","component":[{"name":"Table","id":"menu1"}]},{},{}],"page":1,"loading":false,"numberOfPages":4,"totalItems":null

Comment: {"tab":null,"icons":false,"backgroundColor":"","isdark":false,"tabitems":[{"isEnabled":true,"name":"Tab1","content":"menu1","component":[{"name":"Menu","id":"menu2"}]},{},{}],"page":1,"loading":false,"numberOfPages":4,"totalItems":null

Comment: here the 2 differnt data, it should call watch right?

Comment: Show the code that changes the data

Comment: <component
            :is="config.form.components.results"
            v-show="isComponentActive"
            :config="{
              ...componentConfig,
              page: 1,
              loading: false,
              numberOfPages: 4,
              totalItems: resultsLength,
            }"
         >

Comment: this is the prop which we are sending from one component to another component

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are experiencing the 'reactivity caveat' of vue. It probably depends on how you are mutating the object that you are passing as a config value.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld :config="config"/>
    <button @click="clicked1">This will update</button>
    <button @click="clicked2">This will not update</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data(){
    return {
      config: { x: 1 }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicked1(){
      this.config = { x: this.config.x + 1 }
    },
    clicked2(){
      this.config.x++
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If HelloWorld is watching the config value, it will only update when the entire object is reset.

Try adding a `deep: true` to your watcher.

```
  watch: {
    config: {
      handler(){
        this.watchCounter++
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

I added a codesandbox link with some sample code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-cohen-jgn3d
Click on the buttons and notice that it will not update when "This will not update" is clicked.
Uncomment the `deep: true` inside the HellowWorld component to see how it fixes the issue.

Read more about the reactivity caveats on the official docs.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: i try to add deep:true inside watch , still is not working. it is working if i add immediate:true. but i dont want to add immediate:true because of some scenarios

Comment: Can you please update your question's code sample with what you've tried.